# Angular testing without mocked $http

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, automated-tests

I have a REST client written to be part of an angularJS application that I want to write tests for; I tried with Jasmine (using passthrough on the $httpBackend) but could not get it to talk to the real endpoint at all (which is a requirement).

Does anybody know of a sensible library that allows for this? Or alternatively, a way of wrestling Jasmine into submission?

Comment: You could test it with an e2e test with protractor or something else

Comment: why don't use Mocha if you just want to test back-end rest APIs

Comment: If you want to test with real http requests from client to server, then you do not need to use $httpBackend. I have written tests in jasmine which were requesting real endpoints. Jasmine supports async tests so it is not a problem to write tests which are communicating with real rest api.

Comment: @MarkoCen I haven't investigated Mocha, but I will check it, thanks!

Comment: @thadam I didn't have $httpBackend originally, and it still didn't work as it was forcing a mock backend behind the scenes.

Answer (score 0):

you need to inject first $httpbackend

```
describe('MyController', function() {
 var $httpBackend, $rootScope, createController, authRequestHandler;

 // Set up the module
  beforeEach(module('MyApp'));

  beforeEach(inject(function($injector) {
 // Set up the mock http service responses
 $httpBackend = $injector.get('$httpBackend');
 // backend definition common for all tests
 authRequestHandler = $httpBackend.when('GET', '/auth.py')
                        .respond({userId: 'userX'}, {'A-Token': 'xxx'});

 // Get hold of a scope (i.e. the root scope)
 $rootScope = $injector.get('$rootScope');
 // The $controller service is used to create instances of controllers
 var $controller = $injector.get('$controller');

 createController = function() {
   return $controller('MyController', {'$scope' : $rootScope });
 };
   $httpBackend.when('GET', "/api/rest/").respond(data_to_respond);
  }));
```

next write test cases

```
 it('getTypes - should return 3 car manufacturers', function () {
        service.getTypes().then(function(response) {
            //expect will be here
        });
        $httpBackend.flush();
    });
```

Comment: As I said in my question I do not want to fake the responses - I want my client to talk to a real server.

Comment: not possible when testing you have to fake the response

Comment: Hence me asking if there are other test frameworks where you don't have to, because I was sure that that was a limitation of Jasmine :)

Comment: first of all it's not because you can't i am telling this because you should not do that because then you are violating the principle of unit testing. Main purpose of unit testing is to test individual parts and test it fast, if you use http or real time data it might fail sometime in that case your test cases will fail and eventually resulting in overall result in performance in testing

Comment: I know you're not meant to do this with unit testing, but that's OK, because I am not writing unit tests! (I probably shouldn't have tagged the question with "unit-testing"). How would you get the proper $http service to work with Jasmine then?

Comment: then you should inject $http and make a get call similar to your JS.

Comment: Have you actually tried that? It does not work as the $httpBackend service from angular_mocks takes over. If you remove angular_mocks, it seems to break the whole test file with no way of rectifying it...